# Adding a 'month' 'year' or 'days' to integer field - OpenErp

Tags: python, integer, field, odoo, erp

I'd like to add in an 'integer' field a type of date.

Like = Lifetime of a Product = 6 months

I know i can use integer for the number, like

```
'Lifetime' : fields.integer('Lifetime'),
```

But is there a possibility to add as a parameter, years, months or days?

```
'Lifetime' : fields.integer('Lifetime' , 'Months' , 'Years' ...),
```

And so on?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should use combination of integer field for value and selection field for the duration(month, years) ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add different fields.For example In the settings menu you will be able to see a scheduler> scheduled actions. There you can see interval number and interval unit.